# Can't animate a custom view

Tags: cocoa, macos, mono, monomac

I'm trying to animate the movement of a custom view of mine using the following code (my best translation from objective-c from Apples own documents)

```
        var animDict = new NSMutableDictionary ();
        animDict [NSViewAnimation.TargetKey] = this.View;
        animDict [NSViewAnimation.StartFrameKey] = NSValue.FromRectangleF (this.View.Frame);
        animDict [NSViewAnimation.EndFrameKey] = NSValue.FromRectangleF (new RectangleF (0, 150 * index, 400, 150));

        var theAnim = new NSViewAnimation ();
        theAnim.SetValuesForKeysWithDictionary (animDict);
        theAnim.Duration = 2;
        theAnim.StartAnimation ();
```

However I get the following run-time error when running the app: 2011-05-08 00:53:30.827 EpisodeNext[61715:613] [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key NSViewAnimationTargetKey.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the method `SetValuesForKeysWithDictionary` to pass the animation keys to the `NSViewAnimation` instance.

You must use the `NSViewAnimation(NSDictionary[] viewAnimations)` constructor to pass the animation dictionary.

Comment: Unfortuanettly on doing that i get the following: error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `MonoMac.Foundation.NSMutableDictionary' expression to type `MonoMac.Foundation.NSCoder' (simply removed the SetValuesForKeysWithDictionary method and put animDict in the NSViewAnimation constructor...)

Comment: Have you tried to use "var theAnim = new NSViewAnimation (new NSMutableDictionary[]{ animDict });" ?

Answer (score 2):

// Create the attributes dictionary for the first view.

```
        NSMutableDictionary firstViewDict = new NSMutableDictionary ();


        //var firstViewRect = new NSDictionary[] { };
        firstViewDict [NSViewAnimation.TargetKey] = animateWindow;
        firstViewDict [NSViewAnimation.StartFrameKey] = NSValue.FromRectangleF (new RectangleF (1000, 300 , this.Frame.Width - 40, 0));
        firstViewDict [NSViewAnimation.EndFrameKey]  = NSValue.FromRectangleF (SettingNSWindow.Frame);


        //var NSDict = new NSDictionary[]{ };
        NSDictionary[] NSDict =  new NSDictionary[]{firstViewDict};

        //NSDict.Cast(NSMutableDictionary = (NSDictionary[])firstViewDict;

        NSViewAnimation theAnim = new NSViewAnimation(NSDict);

        //theAnim.SetValuesForKeysWithDictionary (firstViewDict);
        theAnim.Duration = 2;
        theAnim.StartAnimation ();
```